# Inheriting from a template?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm reviewing this code:

```
class WhiteVolatility:public Inverted< IBlackVolatility > {blablabla function declarations}
```

So class WhiteVolatility is inheriting from a template here... and the template class is an abstract class (IBlackVolatility). I'm having trouble understanding exactly what's going on here -- but my actual question is: why use this kind of design? What is the benefit?

let me know in the comments if my question is impossible to answer and you need more information (I can't tell as I am not confident about what is going on)

Comment: This looks like CRTP maybe? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: In that case it would inherit from `Inverted<WhiteVolatility>`

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, it's not, CRTP describes: `template <class B> class D : B {}`, as for use case, difficult to tell without understanding what `IBlackVolatility` provides to `Inverted`

Comment: True, it's not straight CRTP, but some sort of modification.  Unfortunately, I can't know why without knowing the situation.  But it's at least related.

Comment: or not :) It's probably a simple inheritance from a template instance.

Comment: `WhiteVolatility` inherits from a **class**; that class is an instantiation of a template.

Comment: @PeteBecker that makes a lot of sense now, tyvm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Inverted` is a class template. Here a specific instance of the template is used, `Inverted<IBlackVolatility>`, which becomes quite the same thing as any normal class, and `WhiteVolatility` inherits from that normal class. Nothing weird :)

As for semantic, from the name i would guess that the `Inverted` template inverts something in its template parameter (here it seems to be the color, since your black volatility becomes white).

Answer (score 3):

> So class WhiteVolatility is inheriting from a template here...

It's inheriting from a template *specialisation*, not a template. A class template specialisation is a regular class.

> and the template class is an abstract class

No, the template *argument* is (presumably) an abstract class. The specialisation is generated from the template in the usual way by replacing occurrences of the template parameter `IBlackVolatility`.

> why use this kind of design? What is the benefit?

You'd inherit from a template specialisation for exactly the reasons you'd inherit from any other class - to implement an interface it defines, or (perhaps) to incorporate its behaviour into your class. You'd have to look at what `Inverted` does to see why you might want to do that here.